# Problems indexing catalog search - SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1017

Tags: database, error, indexing

Hi I've got this error whent I try to re-index catalog search:

```
oc3an@vl16732:~/www/shell$ php -f indexer.php -- -reindex catalogsearch_fulltext
Catalog Search Index index process unknown error:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1017 Can'                                                      t find file: './dg4qa4t/catalogsearch_fulltext.frm' (errno: 13)' in /home/oc3an/                                                      www/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /home/oc3an/www/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Arr                                                      ay)
#1 /home/oc3an/www/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement                                                      _Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/oc3an/www/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement                                                      _Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /home/oc3an/www/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->exe                                                      cute(Array)
#4 /home/oc3an/www/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Ab                                                      stract->query('DELETE FROM `ca...', Array)
#5 /home/oc3an/www/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo                                                      _Abstract->query('DELETE FROM `ca...', Array)
#6 /home/oc3an/www/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(664): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_                                                      Mysql->query('DELETE FROM `ca...')
#7 /home/oc3an/www/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext/Engi                                                      ne.php(132): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->delete('catalogsearch_f...', Array)
#8 /home/oc3an/www/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php(                                                      296): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext_Engine->cleanIndex(1, NULL)
#9 /home/oc3an/www/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php(                                                      134): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext->cleanIndex(1, NULL)
#10 /home/oc3an/www/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php                                                      (116): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext->_rebuildStoreIndex(1, NULL)
#11 /home/oc3an/www/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Fulltext.php(84): Mag                                                      e_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext->rebuildIndex(NULL, NULL)
#12 /home/oc3an/www/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Indexer/Fulltext.php(                                                      446): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Fulltext->rebuildIndex()
#13 /home/oc3an/www/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(210): Mage_Catalo                                                      gSearch_Model_Indexer_Fulltext->reindexAll()
#14 /home/oc3an/www/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(258): Mage_Index_                                                      Model_Process->reindexAll()
#15 /home/oc3an/www/shell/indexer.php(166): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEve                                                      rything()
#16 /home/oc3an/www/shell/indexer.php(212): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#17 {main}

Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: Gene                                                      ral error: 1017 Can't find file: './dg4qa4t/catalogsearch_fulltext.frm' (errno:                                                       13)' in /home/oc3an/www/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234
Stack trace:
#0 /home/oc3an/www/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement                                                      _Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/oc3an/www/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement                                                      _Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/oc3an/www/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->exe                                                      cute(Array)
#3 /home/oc3an/www/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Ab                                                      stract->query('DELETE FROM `ca...', Array)
#4 /home/oc3an/www/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo                                                      _Abstract->query('DELETE FROM `ca...', Array)
#5 /home/oc3an/www/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(664): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_                                                      Mysql->query('DELETE FROM `ca...')
#6 /home/oc3an/www/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext/Engi                                                      ne.php(132): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->delete('catalogsearch_f...', Array)
#7 /home/oc3an/www/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php(                                                      296): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext_Engine->cleanIndex(1, NULL)
#8 /home/oc3an/www/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php(                                                      134): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext->cleanIndex(1, NULL)
#9 /home/oc3an/www/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php(                                                      116): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext->_rebuildStoreIndex(1, NULL)
#10 /home/oc3an/www/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Fulltext.php(84): Mag                                                      e_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext->rebuildIndex(NULL, NULL)
#11 /home/oc3an/www/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Indexer/Fulltext.php(                                                      446): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Fulltext->rebuildIndex()
#12 /home/oc3an/www/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(210): Mage_Catalo                                                      gSearch_Model_Indexer_Fulltext->reindexAll()
#13 /home/oc3an/www/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(258): Mage_Index_                                                      Model_Process->reindexAll()
#14 /home/oc3an/www/shell/indexer.php(166): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEve                                                      rything()
#15 /home/oc3an/www/shell/indexer.php(212): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#16 {main}
```

Comment: Remove All File form `var\locks` And try to again reindex.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure you are not out of space on your server? This error can also come from a busy server.

Comment: I've tried deleting all locks... no luck...

Answer (score 1):

That's a fairly serious error indicating that your tables are corrupt.

It could be caused by anything, full filesystem, unclean MySQL restart etc.

Try a table repair and hope for the best.

```
mysqlcheck -Ar
```